# Block reward from transaction regarding block's gas limit

Tags: transactions, gas-limit, gas-price, reward

maybe it's a silly question or remark, but given that the current block gas limit is about **8,000,000** and the average *gasPrice* is about '**15Gwei**' ( I roughly looked at the chart *"Transaction Count by Gas Price*" chart on ethgasstation.info and calculated the average ), then the total amount of dollars a miner can earn from that block is about:

### **$60** = (**15**Gwei * **8,000,000**(gas limit) * pricePerGweiInDolars(~**$0.0..1**)).

Or you can also use the gas-price-estimator on that same website, just put **8,000,000** as gas used and slide the slider to the very right, for 20Gwei.
For me it's incredibly low compared to the reward he gains from mining the block ( it's currently 3 ETH, right?).
I am posting it beacuse I am almost sure I misunderstood something. Can someone clarify, or is the transaction reward indeed so low ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your math is correct. 15 Gwei multiplied by the gas limit is about 0.12 ether (as you determined). During higher congestion in early January (I think that was largely post-Cryptokitties, but I might be mistaken), the price as about 6 times higher and the price of ether (in USD) was about 2x as much as it is now (give or take), so in USD, the price of a transaction was starting to get pretty hefty compared to calmer times.

In any case, 0.12 ether is a 4% "bonus" per block mined, assuming full blocks. Assuming your odds of mining a block aren't decreased by an off-setting amount, it only helps to include those transactions.

Whether it's low or high, well, that's subjective. If I were paying for groceries and someone offered me 4% off my bill without any catch, I'd take it. And, who knows, if Ethereum becomes very commonplace and the price per ether goes up, that $60 might be worth $600 or $6000. I'm guessing the price for gas will go down or the gas price of transactions will drop before 0.12 ether is worth much more than $6000. Then again, I wouldn't have guessed people would pay $100+ to conduct a "basic" Bitcoin transaction (with the UXTO method of sending transactions making spending multiple inputs quite expensive).